# pyparsing verilog module pins info

Tags: python, module, verilog, pyparsing, pins

I am trying to get the following info from a Verilog file:

- module name
- pinslist
- pins info (pinName or busName (and vector range), direction)

For example, below a Verilog file:

```
module DMU  (
       A, B, C, 
       vdd, Z, Q, QN );

output Z;
input  A, B,
       C, D;

inout vdd;

output [127:0] Q;
output [18:0] QN;  //my comment

endmodule
```

The code I have implemented:

```
range = LBRACK + Word(nums) + COLON + Word(nums) + RBRACK
inputDecl = Group("input" + Optional(range) + Group(OneOrMore(Word(alphanums+","), stopOn=SEMI))).setResultsName("inputPins")
inoutDecl = Group("inout" + Optional(range) + Group(OneOrMore(Word(alphanums+","), stopOn=SEMI))).setResultsName("inoutPins")
outputDecl = Group("output" + Optional(range) + Group(OneOrMore(Word(alphanums+","), stopOn=SEMI))).setResultsName("outputPins")

pinsDecl = ~Keyword("endmodule") + (
            inputDecl |
            inoutDecl |
            outputDecl
            )

token_module = Keyword("module") + Word(alphanums).setResultsName("moduleName") + LPAR + \
               Group(OneOrMore(Word(alphanums+","), stopOn=RPAR).setResultsName("pinsList")) + SEMI + pinsDecl
```

I have the following error I cannot solve:

```
File "/sw/freetools/python/3.7.2/rh60_64/modules_base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 2625, in parseImpl
    raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected ";" (at char 52), (line:3, col:22)
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Please note that the A,B,C, D pinslist into the verilog file can be on multiple lines:

Comment: No need to comment with additional information. You should [edit] that into the question itself

Comment: You are missing the RPAR before the SEMI. Pyparsing exceptions aren't always superhelpful, but this time, I think it is spot on: `Expected ";" (at char 52), (line:3, col:22)` directs you to this line: `vdd, Z, Q, QN );`, and the character in column 22 (1-based) is ')'.  Also, change `Group(OneOrMore(Word(alphanums+","), stopOn=RPAR).setResultsName("pinsList"))` to `Group(delimitedList(Word(alphas, alphanums)).setResultsName("pinsList")`, so that you don't mix the ','s in with the pin names.  Lastly, check out the verilog parser that is included in the pyparsing examples directory.

Comment: thanks Paul, I will try your update, I have already tested the example_parser.py in the pyparsing 2.4.7 package examples, however it does not do what I want (there are some crahes on some lines parsing, and I do not need to parse other data than the pins info)